# Matlab interactive calculation of slope between two points

Tags: matlab

I create a figure with toggle button on its toolbar by uitoggletool. The callback function for it is shown below:

```
function calc_slope(handle,event)

on = get(handle,'State');

if strcmpi(on,'on') || strcmpi(on,'off'),
   xy=imline;

   addNewPositionCallback(xy,@(xy)...
       title(['\DeltaY/\DeltaX = ',num2str((xy(4)-xy(3))/(xy(2)-xy(1))),...
             '[\DeltaX = ',num2str(xy(2)-xy(1)),...
             ',\DeltaY = ',num2str((xy(4)-xy(3))),']']));
end
```

As you can see, I'm trying to calculate the slope between two points on a curve. The code is something I found in the web that's pretty close to what I'm trying to. The 'addNewPositionCallback" is executed in both 'On' and 'Off' state, but it's merely a means to repeat the process as many times as a user wants. What I really want to do is number 4 and 5 below.

What I really want to do is as follows:

1. "Draggable" points "snapped" to the nearest curve
2. The connecting line shows
3. Delta X, delta Y, and the slope provided in a "text box" drawn near
   the curve
4. Draw as many lines as needed while in the 'On' state
5. Delete all lines and 'text' boxes when toggle button is set to 'Off'

The imline function gives a bunch of features such as different line colors. I can care less on those. The major "wants" are the snapping and the text box.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Eric